# c programming how to get list of leaves from tree

Tags: c

I have a binary tree and I need to make a list of all the leaves

the tree define is:

```
typedef struct tree {
    TreeNode* root;
    List leafList;  
} Tree;
```

treeNode define:

```
typedef struct  treeNode {
    int data;
    struct treeNode* parent;
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
} TreeNode;
```

list define

```
typedef struct list {
ListNode* head;
ListNode* tail;
```

} List;
listNode define

```
typedef struct listNode {
    int data;
    struct listNode* next;
} ListNode;
```

On my first step I built the tree (which is fine).
Now on my second step I need to make a list from all leaves.
for ex. the following tree will return list of 1->2->5->7

```
    6
   / \
  4   3
 /\   /\
1  2 5  7
```

this is what I got so far

my tree builder function:

```
Tree BuildTreeFromArrayWithLeafList(int *arr, int size)
{
    Tree T;
    T.root = BuildTreeRec(arr, size); // till here all working fine
    T.leafList.head = BuildLeafList(T.root); //function fail
    return T;
}
```

Now for my problem
BuildLeafList function need to build list of tree leaves and return it, but no matter how I change my code it keeps failing.
This is my BuildLeafList function code:

```
ListNode* BuildLeafList(TreeNode *tn)
{
    ListNode *temp;

    if (tn == NULL)
        return;
    if (tn->left == NULL && tn->right == NULL)
        return CreateListNode(tn->data);

    temp = BuildLeafList(tn->left);
    temp->next = BuildLeafList(tn->right);

    return temp;
}
```

Can someone please help me make this function build list of leaves and return it.

This is how it should look in the end
[image of tree struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/441Pu.png)

Appreciate any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post all the code and don't edit it on SO (BuildList vs BuildLeafList). We don't know how you built the tree, how can be sure it is correct? We don't know what you get, what means function fail? You also forgot to create nodes in list for node that are not leaves in tree...

Comment: You did not indicate what you problem is, or what your question is.

Comment: I just renamed it, I'm still trying to figure my problem and I didn't notice I reanemd my function, but this is not the reason for my problem, function still keep failing

Comment: @StephenRauch I need BuildLeafList function to return list of the tree leaves and it wont. This is my problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do a normal ordered recursion and check whether `leafList == NULL` to determine whether your node was a leaf?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm not sure I'm following you, are you saying build a recursion on my leafList insted of the tree?

Comment: Is this homework? The same question with the same example is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548834/c-binary-tree-how-to-make-list-from-tree-leaves

Answer (score 0):

Returning 'temp' is the problem here. As you change from left subtree to right subtree, the last node is lost.

Node 6, temp == NULL, terminating conditions do not satisfy, hence calls buildleaflist(tn->left == 4)

Node 4, temp == NULL, terminating conditions do not satisfy, hence calls buildleaflist(tn->left == 1)

Node 1, temp == NULL, terminating conditions satisfy, hence node is allocated and returns to previous level (Node 4).

Node 4, temp->data == 1, calls buildleaflist((tn->right == 2)

Node 2, temp == NULL, terminating conditions satisfy, hence node is allocated and returns to previous level (Node 4).

Node 4, temp->next = (node allocated for 2). List looks like 1->2, temp is pointing to 1. Node 4 returns to Node 6.

Node 6, temp->data is 1.  calls buildleaflist(tn->right == 3).

Node 3, temp == NULL, terminating conditions do not satisfy, calls buildleaflist(tn->left == 5)

Node 5, temp == NULL, terminating conditions satisfy, hence allocates node and returns to Node 3.

Node 3, temp->data == 5, calls buildleaflist(tn->right == 7).

Node 7, temp == NULL, terminating conditions satisfy, hence allocates node and returns to Node 3.

Node 3, temp->next = (Node 7). hence the list (from Node 3's context) looks like 5->7. Node 3 returns to Node 6.

Here the problem lies. temp is Node 6 is still pointing to '1'. As a result, when you execute temp->next=buildleaflist(tn->right), Node 2 gets lost. The list now looks like 1->5->7.

I suggest that you pass a double pointer to buildleaflist() which can be used to carry the head of the list. Then, return (temp->next) from buildleaflist().

```
ListNode* BuildLeafList(TreeNode *tn, TreeNode **head)
{
    ListNode *temp;

    if (tn == NULL)
        return;
    if (tn->left == NULL && tn->right == NULL)
        return CreateListNode(tn->data);

    temp = BuildLeafList(tn->left);
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp;
    }
    temp->next = BuildLeafList(tn->right);

    return temp->next;
}
```