# C binary tree, How to make list from tree leaves

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to build list of all the leaves in tree
for example, I have the following tree:

```
    6
   / \
  4   3
 /\   /\
1  2 5  7
```

treeNode typedef

```
typedef struct  treeNode {
    int data;
    struct treeNode* parent;
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
} TreeNode;
```

my list should be 1->2->5->7

list typedef

```
typedef struct list {
        ListNode* head;
        ListNode* tail;
    } List;
```

listNode typedef

```
  typedef struct listNode {
        int data;
        struct listNode* next;
    } ListNode;
```

Listnode->data = TreeNode->data; (the listnode struct data)

The function should be generic, I tired several recursion functions but none worked

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do an in-order traversal and check for leaf nodes.

Comment: Try still another recursive function. That is the natural way to go. Perhaps you could post your best attempt and describe how it fails.

Comment: Are you both just students from the same institute that don't like doing your own homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541946/c-programming-how-to-get-list-of-leaves-from-tree

Comment: @StoryTeller I was about to post the same link as they are asking about the very same tree values.

Comment: @WeatherVane - You may as well close the other as a dup

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea would be to traverse the tree [in-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order), and push every leaf node you encounter to the list. Something like the following:

```
populateList(node)
  if(node == null) return

  populateList(node->left)

  if (node->left == null && node->right == null)
    pushToList(node)
    return

  populateList(node->right)
```

Comment: I did the same but my problem is to return the new list to the refferer function

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with recursion, as you tried. What you have to do is first check whether you've reached a leaf node, ie. if left and right pointers are `NULL`, and in that case you add the node to the list. The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
getLeavesList(root) {
    if root is NULL: return
    if root is leaf_node: add_to_leaves_list(root)
    getLeavesList(root -> left)
    getLeavesList(root -> right)
}
```

You can adapt this code to any programming language. So, if the root is NULL, this is, if the function received no valid pointer, then return an error message. If the root is a leaf, this is, if both left and right child nodes are NULL, the you have to add it to the list of leaf nodes. Then you recursively call the function with the left and right child nodes.